# Template settings won't be saved. How to change the logo?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, templates

I have the latest joomla version installed and I use [Looksmart template](http://themeforest.net/item/looksmart-responsive-multipurpose-joomla-theme/7384561). The template editor isn't working, I can't save my changes. I want to remove the logo, and add another one, which is more like a banner on top of the menu. How to do it?

The strange thing is I go to `looksmart/template/images/logo.png/` I replace that, nothing changes, I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this location `looksmart/template/images/logo.png/` really exist, in your installation?

I checked in the live preview of your template and the logo image exist at this location: `/images/sampledata/logo.png`.

So, you can replace that one with your own logo.

But in any case contact the template developer to report the issues you have, as you will want to be able to edit/save settings of your template in the backend.

## Update

In your live site, I see the logo image is here:

```
templates/looksmart_template/images/presets/preset1/logo.png
```

Remember to Clear caches, after changes to make sure if it you did it right.

Comment: @Lynob: In your live site the logo is here:  templates/looksmart_template/images/presets/preset1/logo.png. Remember to Clear caches, after changes to make sure if it you did it right.

Comment: can you answer this Sir? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16982/how-to-add-a-banner-on-top-of-the-navigation-bar